# android room database schema invalid error caused by primaryKeyPosition

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I have a simple database with few tables.i have implemented room entities for tables.i'm getting this error and it's saying that my schema is invalid.but i found it very similar only difference is column order and primaryKeyPosition.

error message(i have omitted the foreign keys as they are equal)

```
Expected:

TableInfo{name='am',
 columns={name=Column{name='name', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'},
 symbol=Column{name='symbol', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'},
 a_number=Column{name='a_number', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'},
 a_id=Column{name='a_id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}},


Found:

TableInfo{name='am',
 columns={symbol=Column{name='symbol', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'},
 name=Column{name='name', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'},
 a_number=Column{name='a_number', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'},
 a_id=Column{name='a_id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=2, defaultValue='null'}},
```

i have attached a image to clarify the difference

[image]

as you can see only differences are
 * 1st and 2nd table column order is different
 * primaryKeyPosition is different in last column

my entity class

```
@Entity(tableName = "am",
        foreignKeys = {
                @ForeignKey(entity = ATypes.class,
                        parentColumns = "a_id",
                        childColumns = "a_id"),
        },
        indices = {@Index("a_id")}
)
public class Am {

    public String name;
    public String symbol;
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "a_number")
    public int aNumber;

    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "a_id")
    public Integer aId;

}
```

my question how can i change the column order or primaryKeyPosition in order to match expected schema.

Comment: Can you update your question with your entity class?

Comment: @HenriqueVasconcellos updated with entity class

Comment: What calls my attention here is that you are not indexing your primary key as well, have you tried that?
Do you have other room relations working? I can provide a working sample if you need to compare.

Comment: @HenriqueVasconcellos i have 2 tables for now.it worked before i add the 2nd table and the relation.i will try adding index

Comment: Most likely that is the issue!! If it doesn't work, post your relation configuration as well and your parent entity!

Comment: @HenriqueVasconcellos thanks .you are right.it's the indexes that caused the issue.

Comment: great! If you dont mind I will provide an answer so we can "close" this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the index for your primary key!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Robolectric the problem may be caused by this issue https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/4209

I had the same issues and I solved it with https://github.com/guness/RobolectricSQLite

Comment: i'm using sqlite and DB Browser (SQLite) for editing

Comment: In your question is not metioned, but by the screen I thought that you are doing tests. That library is ment to be used in tests if you are using robolectric